# I need help making a start button that only works when you press it

Tags: javascript, button, processing

I'm planning on making a start button for my game, however it only works when I hover over it, and when I take my mouse off it goes back to start up screen. I'd like to know how I can do it to only start on the playing screen if I press on the start button, thanks.

Comment: The current button code includes:  float aaaa = 165; float bbbb = 140; float cccc= 150; float dddd= 80;     rect(aaaa,bbbb,cccc,dddd);   if(mouseX>aaaa && mouseX<aaaa+cccc && mouseY>bbbb && mouseY<bbbb+dddd){

Answer (score 1):

Please post your code as a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing exactly where you're stuck.

But more generally, you need to [break your problem down into smaller steps](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and then approach those steps one at a time. You need to work in isolation, and maybe even work in a separate example program that only tests one thing.

For example, it sounds like you've got two problems: can you create a sketch that consists of multiple screens? Don't worry about the button yet, just cycle through the screens when the user clicks anywhere in the window.

Separately from that, can you create a button that prints a message to the console when you click on it? You'll have to use basic [point-rectangle collision detection](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/collision-detection) to detect when the mouse is inside the button.

It's hard to help with general "how do I do this" type questions other than by pointing you to Google and some tutorials. So please try something out and post a MCVE in a new question if you get stuck. Good luck.

Comment: I have broken it down into smaller steps and all, but I still can't find out why it doesn't work, and where I have gone wrong.